# websites doesnt load & restricted from accessing?

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, firefox, restricted-access

my company as installed ubuntu 14.04 14.04 LTS ON NEW COMPUTER

DEVICE NAME: CTEL-DESKTOP
MEMORY 1.9 GIB
PROCESSOR INTEL CELERON(R) CPUJ1900@1.99GHz *4
GRAPHICS INTEL BAY TRAIL X86/MMX/SSE2
OS TYPE 32-BIT
DISK 60.9 GB

NOTE:

1) CPU LOOKS PORTABLE.

2) INTERNET ACCESS AVAILABLE THROUGH AIRTEL BROADBAND  TOWER WIRELESSLY

3) NO LAN CONNECTIONS USED.

I HAVE ONLY ACCESS  TO SINGLE  GOVERNMENT WEBSITE .

WHEN I LOAD THAT WEBSITE  IT SHOWS IN THE BROWSER ADDRESS LIKE :

" LOCALHOST/ETC.ETC.ETC/ETC  "

INSTEAD OF WWW.APBCL.COM

and my problem is remaining all websites are restricted from accessing.

when I try to open google it displays server not found.

Only firefox is installed on my system. Any open dns or vpns or proxy type 
or any types of software are not installed. How can I access to all websites? Before he restricted I saw browser history that he accessed to so many websites.

Comment: No need for everything to be in capitals...

Comment: paste `/etc/resolv.conf` lines here.

Comment: You can check if your DNS is working for that website for which you have access to.